# Auto Select Middle Visible Cell Of Collection View

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to select and highlight the middle cell of the visible cells in a collection view at any given time. The collection view in question displays days for six months forwards and back.

I've tried using the scroll view delegates and the collection view delegates. But all that works is select and highlight code in `didSelectItem()` collection view delegate.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("delegate called")
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.highlightCellGreen()
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? ClientListDateCollectionViewCell{
        monthLabel.text = cell.monthName
        monthLabel.text = monthLabel.text?.capitalized

}
```

I tried to select the middle cell while scrolling using the `viewDidScroll()` delegate. But, I wasn't able to get the output I wanted.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

       let visibleCellCount = dateCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.count
       let cellCount = dateCollectionView.visibleCells.count
let visibleCells = dateCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems[visibleCellCount-1/2]
      if visibleCellCount>0{
       let middle = visibleCellCount/2
       let midValue = dateCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems[middle]
           dateCollectionView.selectItem(at: midValue, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
}
```

How do I go about selecting the middle cell?

edit 1: The collection view starts on the leftmost point and then scrolls to the middle i.e, today's date

Comment: `let middle = visibleCellCount/2` what is this!!!

Comment: it's not that simple

Comment: @ SPatel I'd glady learn how to do it properly. I just started out with swift. Please help me understand how it is supposed to be done

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing this? Is there a screenshot?

Comment: @Nullable I'm trying to make a date picker of sorts with collection view that displays days and a label below the collection displays the current month of the selected day

Comment: Do you want to customize your calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegate of **UICollectionView** (i.e: didHighlightItemAtIndexPath). just make sure to call collection view delegates on your desired time by calling reload function

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

and in you collection view delegate just do this

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    var cell : UICollectionViewCell = UICollectionViewCell()

    self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath = indexPath
    //change highlighted color as of your need
    cell.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 25, green: 118, blue: 210).cgColor
    }
```

This will highlight you selected item

Comment: I want to keep the middle cell of the visible cells selected and highlighted while I'm scrolling through the collection view. The answer that you've provided only highlights a given cell.

Comment: So for this purpose you can use delegate function of collection view that returns array of visible indexes(i.e:  public func indexPathsForVisibleItems()). then you have to divide count of array with 2 this will return you the middle index. then just set cell.setSelected = true. and set highlighted. this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Disable multiple selection (or selection entirely?) to make things easier.

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

On `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` get the center point of the screen as `CGpoint`.

```
let center = collectionView.center
```

Use that information to get the index path of the center item

```
let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: center)
```

Select the item

```
collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)
```

Comment: The collection just keeps scrolling without selecting the cell and on observing with the break point, it shows that index path at that point is zero

Comment: Try converting point to collection view's coordinate space. `let converted = self.view.convert(center, to: self.collectionView)` and use this new point.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have the horizontal of displaying, and you want to have the auto scroll to the center of your item in datasource.

1. Creating a method and calling it immediately after your collection view is completely configured:

   ```
   func scrollToCenterIndex() {
       let centerIndex = LIST_OF_YOUR_DATA_SOURCE.count / 2
       let indexPath = IndexPath(item: centerIndex, section: 0)
       self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath,
                                        at: .right,
                                        animated: false)
    }
   ```
2. Inside the method:

   ```
   public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CELL,
                                                           for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {
                                                             fatalError("Cannot create cell")
       }

       If indexPath.row == LIST_OF_YOUR_DATA_SOURCE.count / 2  {
           // perform your hight light color to the cell
       } else {
           // reset your hight light color to default color
       }
       let model = LIST_OF_YOUR_DATA_SOURCE[indexPath.row] 
       cell.configure(model)

       return cell
     }
   ```

Comment: I've already implemented something like this. What I want is that, every time I scroll the collection view, I need the middle cell to be selected and highlighted

Comment: I don’t understand well about what you need.
So this is what you need, right?
Suppose that you have 23 items, and the number of cell displayed in screen is 11 items - index 0 to 10,
So the middle items will be at index 5 which is hight light as selected.
After you scroll to a bit, the items will display from of index 1 to 11, and the middle will be at index 6 which will be hight light and the index 5 will be reset, and so on.
Is it correct with what you need?

Comment: I added a sample with table view. Hopefully, It can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a method to get the center point of collection view, and use this value to get the the middle of visible cell.

```
let centerPoint = self.view.convert(collectionView.center, to: collection)
```

Here is an example I did it with a tableView. You can apply it to your collection view with the same approach.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  var dataSource = Array(1...31)
  var centerIndex: IndexPath?

  func setCellSelected(cell: UITableViewCell, _ selected: Bool) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = selected ? .green : .white
  }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    dataSource.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELL")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = String(dataSource[indexPath.row])

    let center = self.view.convert(tableView.center, to: tableView)
    if let index = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: center), let cell = cell {
      setCellSelected(cell: cell, indexPath.row == index.row)
    }
    return cell!
  }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // reset the previous hight light cell
    if let centerIndex = centerIndex, let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: centerIndex) {
      setCellSelected(cell: cell, false)
    }
    // set hight light to a new center cell
    let center = self.view.convert(tableView.center, to: tableView)
    if let index = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: center), let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index) {
      setCellSelected(cell: cell, true)
      centerIndex = index
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to do the auto-selection of the middle visible cell of the collection view, and I got the solution, here is the solution:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
// Reload Collection View
collectionView.reloadData()
// Find centre point of collection view
let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: collectionView.center.x + collectionView.contentOffset.x, y: collectionView.center.y + collectionView.contentOffset.y)
// Find index path using centre point
guard let newIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) else { return }
// Select the new centre item
collectionView.selectItem(at: newIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)   }
```

You need to use the Scroll view delegate function, scrollViewDidEndDecelerating. Reload the collection view first. Second, find the center visible point of the collection view. Third, using the center visible point, find the indexPath of collection view and finally use the index to select the item in the collection view.

I know I answered this question a little late, still thinking that it will be helpful for someone.

Cheers!

Comment: what does this line do?
scrollingDelegate?.scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView)

Comment: @krishnaravichander please ignore that line brother, it will work fine. I was using this line of code for my requirement, accidentally added here (I will remove it now). Thanks for the comment.